# Removing mutable collections and making it look more scala style

Tags: scala, immutability

I have a List[User] and I want to create a map where I can lookup a locationId and get a list of all the users who are associated with that locationId.

```
case class User(id: Int, locationId: Int, ....)
```

The code I have now is very java like, was hoping someone could help converting this to be more idiomatic scala.  I am using mutable lists but maybe they have to be here in this case.

```
  lazy val usersMap: Map[Int, mutable.ListBuffer[User]] = {
        val map = new mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.ListBuffer[User]]
        for(user <- users) {
          if(map.contains(user.locationId)) {
            map(user.locationId) += user
          } else {
            val lb = mutable.ListBuffer.empty[User]
            lb += user
            map.put(user.locationId, lb)
          }
        }
        map.toMap
    }
```

Another requirement I have is to sort the List[User] by user.Id.  So when I do map(3) I get a list of users that are already sorted by user.id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing you're starting with some `List[User]`, you can use `groupBy` to create a `Map[Int, List[User]]`, where each key is a unique `locationId`, and each `List[User]` within the map is associated with that `locationId` as its key. In order to then sort each list of users, you can then use `mapValues` on the result `Map`.

```
val users = List(User(1, 1), User(2, 1), User(3, 4), User(4, 5), User(7, 4), User(8, 5))

lazy val usersMap: Map[Int, List[User]] = 
    users.groupBy(_.locationId).mapValues(_.sortBy(_.id))   

usersMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[User]] = Map(
     5 -> List(User(4,5), User(8,5)), 
     4 -> List(User(3,4), User(7,4)), 
     1 -> List(User(1,1), User(2,1))
)
```